# Python API connection in global variable - assignment doesn't work

Tags: python, api, global-variables

```
api_connection = None


def get_connection():
    global api_connection
    if api_connection is None:
        api_connection = APIConnection(SERVER)
        return api_connection
    else:
        return api_connection
```

I'm trying to store my API connection instance in a global variable for later reuse. To access or instantiate it I use the above function. Unfortunately the api_connection variable doesn't change after calling the function. What am I doing wrong?

edit: 
and this confuses me even more

```
>>> c = get_connection()
>>> c == get_connection()
True
>>> c is get_connection()
True
>>> c is api_connection
False
>>> api_connection
>>> api_connection is None
True
```

Comment: I think your confusion comes from how you're defining `api_connection` in your shell there. Please show how you did that.

Comment: thats just the ipython shell of pycharm

Comment: Yes but *exactly how did you define or import api_connection there*?

Comment: I ran the file with the above code in pycharm and then I used the python console

Comment: FFS. **What code did you use to define or import api_connection in that console session**?

Comment: exactly the code I posted above. ```api_connection = None``` That code is part of a file where the APIConnection class is defined. I then ran the code in pycharm and used the python console to test it

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I modified your code as following for visualisation:

```
>>> api_connection = None
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def get_connection():
...     global api_connection
...     if api_connection is None:
...         api_connection = 10
...         return api_connection
...     else:
...         return api_connection
... 
>>> print(api_connection)
None
>>> get_connection()
10
>>> print(api_connection)
10
```

I think this method `APIConnection(SERVER)` is returning None as well. That's why you'r seeing no change in variable. Can you check the out of this method?

Comment: its not returning none, it's returning the connection object